# PHP CURL call behaving asynchronously

Tags: php, curl, ffmpeg, cron

I have 2 different servers. In server 2 I have a API function which basically does video conversion of the file and generates thumbs. I have created logs after each functions in server 2 and server1 so that I can check what is happening in the server. From server1 I make a curl call which calls server2 API and sends necessary info like path and type of file etc to server2. The server to converts the media files and generate thumbs. All this process is done using ffmpeg and then server2 uploads converted video to rackspace cloud.
This process runs in a cron job. In the cron job server1 reads media file path from a table and sends them one by one to server 2 by curl call.

**Problem:** This process takes time and what is happening that when server2 code is processing 1st video file server1 sends another video file. It does not wait for the response of server 2. Now server two is processing 1st and second then meanwhile server1 sends another then all videos in server two processed.Server two sends response for all videos one by one. I can see whole process in logs. But I'm not getting how this can be happen in PHP. As far as I read that PHP lines executes one by one. So server 1 should wait for response of server2.

Note: I have increased  curl timeout also but that also does not work.

Comment: maybe a little bit of code extracts on the calls that you use to get the files ?

Comment: Its a simple code: I have a query that gets number of media from a table. There is a foreach loop that sends all files one by one to server 2. Within foreach loop there is curl call to server2 API

Comment: it is difficult to post code in comments so you may Edit your question directly, paste the parts at the end. Also don't forget to format "as code" using selection + the swirl brace button :)

Comment: Thanx @v.oddou but now I have edited code completely to made it work. I have changed whole process. Will try to post a demo by creating same process again.  `Hope that will help` :)